# Looping through a JSON object containing more objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON object of asteroid data of the following form:

```
    {
  "links" : {
    "next" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-14&end_date=2018-06-21&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
    "prev" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-05-31&end_date=2018-06-07&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
    "self" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-07&end_date=2018-06-14&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
  },
  "element_count" : 40,
  "near_earth_objects" : {
    "2018-06-09" : [ {
      "links" : {
        "self" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2162474?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
      },
      "neo_reference_id" : "2162474",
      "name" : "162474 (2000 LB16)",
      "nasa_jpl_url" : "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2162474",
      "absolute_magnitude_h" : 18.5,
      "estimated_diameter" : {
        "kilometers" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 0.5303407233,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 1.1858779086
        },
        "meters" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 530.3407233187,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 1185.8779085771
        },
        "miles" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 0.3295383456,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 0.7368701419
        },
        "feet" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 1739.963058693,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 3890.675677576
        }
      },
      "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid" : true,
      "close_approach_data" : [ {
        "close_approach_date" : "2018-06-09",
        "epoch_date_close_approach" : 1528527600000,
        "relative_velocity" : {
          "kilometers_per_second" : "29.5006815383",
          "kilometers_per_hour" : "106202.4535379664",
          "miles_per_hour" : "65990.074533077"
        },
        "miss_distance" : {
          "astronomical" : "0.2778177136",
          "lunar" : "108.0710983276",
          "kilometers" : "41560940",
          "miles" : "25824772"
        },
        "orbiting_body" : "Earth"
      } ]
    "2018-06-07" : [...
        ]
```

I am trying to loop through it, accessing just the name of each asteroid within the array of objects associated with todays date "2018-06-07", displaying the name of each in an html page

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
// get JSON data for todays asteroids
$.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date="+today+"&api_key="+API_KEY, function(result) {


    // iterate over all keys
    for (let x in result) {

        // if key is 'near_earth_objects'
        if (x == 'near_earth_objects') {

            // iterate over dates in 'near_earth_objects'
            for (y in result.near_earth_objects) {

                // if todays date
                if (y == result.near_earth_objects[today]) {

                    // loop over array of objects for todays date
                    for (let i=0; i<result.near_earth_objects[today].length; i++) {


                        let id = 'n'+(i+1);

                        let output = document.getElementById(id);
                        output.innerhtml = result.near_earth_objects[today][i].name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However my html divs are showing blank. Any ideas?

p.s. 'today' is a variable i've already defined to be todays date with the correct format "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: Any console errors? Make sure first you're even getting to the innermost loop by adding a console.log(id) somewhere in there, then seeing if this outputs in the console next time you run this function

Comment: Are you sure you have any divs in your DOM with id = "n1", "n2", etc. ?

Comment: It should be `output.innerHTML`, just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using loops to select the property. You directly select the right array. Then loop over its elements and append them to the document.

I took some more data from nasa.gov to show you:

```js
result.near_earth_objects["2018-06-18"].forEach(object => {

  const el = document.createElement('div')
  el.innerHTML = object.name

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el)

});
```

```html
<script>
  const result = {  
   "links":{  
      "next":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-21&end_date=2018-06-28&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
      "prev":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-07&end_date=2018-06-14&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
      "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-14&end_date=2018-06-21&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
   },
   "element_count":38,
   "near_earth_objects":{
      "2018-06-18":[  
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3825034?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3825034",
            "name":"(2018 KR2)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3825034",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":19.136,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.3956899106,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.884789538
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":395.6899105531,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":884.7895380075
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.2458702354,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.54978256
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":1298.1952861389,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":2902.8529078765
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-18",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529305200000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"12.0438743406",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"43357.9476263051",
                     "miles_per_hour":"26940.9425125783"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.3064664713",
                     "lunar":"119.2154541016",
                     "kilometers":"45846732",
                     "miles":"28487838"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3563152?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3563152",
            "name":"(2011 GA62)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3563152",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":18.9,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.4411182,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.9863702813
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":441.1181999969,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":986.3702813054
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.2740980571,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.6129018881
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":1447.2382352778,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":3236.1230737181
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-18",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529305200000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"7.9455926818",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"28604.1336544372",
                     "miles_per_hour":"17773.4962698918"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.1550728286",
                     "lunar":"60.3233299255",
                     "kilometers":"23198564",
                     "miles":"14414920"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3733265?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3733265",
            "name":"(2015 VD2)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3733265",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":24.6,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0319561887,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0714562102
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":31.9561886721,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":71.4562101727
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0198566489,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0444008168
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":104.8431420431,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":234.436392583
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-18",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529305200000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"16.5811851502",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"59692.2665406091",
                     "miles_per_hour":"37090.4530624135"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.3445160884",
                     "lunar":"134.0167694092",
                     "kilometers":"51538876",
                     "miles":"32024772"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "2018-06-17":[  
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2162168?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"2162168",
            "name":"162168 (1999 GT6)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2162168",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":17.0,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":1.0581688593,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":2.3661375011
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":1058.1688593312,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":2366.137501138
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.6575154423,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":1.4702492252
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":3471.6827204482,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":7762.9185592335
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-17",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529218800000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"9.6198699215",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"34631.5317173891",
                     "miles_per_hour":"21518.6870273966"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.2630390442",
                     "lunar":"102.3221893311",
                     "kilometers":"39350084",
                     "miles":"24451008"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3785933?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3785933",
            "name":"(2017 UA)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3785933",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":28.5,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0053034072,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0118587791
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":5.3034072332,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":11.8587790858
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0032953835,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0073687014
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":17.3996305869,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":38.9067567758
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-17",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529218800000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"7.3524855265",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"26468.94789533",
                     "miles_per_hour":"16446.7748741844"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.3811914985",
                     "lunar":"148.283493042",
                     "kilometers":"57025436",
                     "miles":"35433964"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3801999?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3801999",
            "name":"(2018 FS1)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3801999",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":20.8,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.1838886721,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.411187571
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":183.8886720703,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":411.1875710413
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.1142630881,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.2555000322
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":603.309310875,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":1349.040630575
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-17",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529218800000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"11.6654375478",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"41995.5751720393",
                     "miles_per_hour":"26094.4172506485"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.3818340382",
                     "lunar":"148.5334320068",
                     "kilometers":"57121560",
                     "miles":"35493692"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "2018-06-16":[  
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3279436?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3279436",
            "name":"(2005 LU3)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3279436",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":26.2,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0152951935,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0342010925
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":15.2951935344,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":34.201092472
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0095039897,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.021251567
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":50.1810827555,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":112.2083122258
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"16.9895489303",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"61162.3761489486",
                     "miles_per_hour":"38003.9220021064"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.2620137139",
                     "lunar":"101.9233322144",
                     "kilometers":"39196692",
                     "miles":"24355696"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3283835?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3283835",
            "name":"(2005 NW44)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3283835",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":20.4,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.2210828104,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.4943561926
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":221.0828103591,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":494.3561926196
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.137374447,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.3071786018
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":725.3373275385,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":1621.9035709942
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"12.0629690223",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"43426.6884801364",
                     "miles_per_hour":"26983.6554058936"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.0548729113",
                     "lunar":"21.3455619812",
                     "kilometers":"8208871",
                     "miles":"5100756"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3395958?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3395958",
            "name":"(2007 WP3)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3395958",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":23.5,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0530340723,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.1185877909
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":53.0340723319,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":118.5877908577
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0329538346,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0736870142
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":173.9963058693,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":389.0675677576
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"15.7057349157",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"56540.6456964908",
                     "miles_per_hour":"35132.1584329112"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.1746641507",
                     "lunar":"67.9443588257",
                     "kilometers":"26129386",
                     "miles":"16236048"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3429684?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3429684",
            "name":"(2008 TZ)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3429684",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":25.4,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.022108281,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0494356193
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":22.1082810359,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":49.435619262
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0137374447,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0307178602
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":72.5337327539,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":162.1903570994
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"17.3250625132",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"62370.2250473537",
                     "miles_per_hour":"38754.4323356737"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.1975837242",
                     "lunar":"76.8600692749",
                     "kilometers":"29558104",
                     "miles":"18366554"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3667048?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3667048",
            "name":"(2014 GQ17)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3667048",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":27.1,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0101054342,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0225964377
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":10.1054341542,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":22.5964377109
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0062792237,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0140407711
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":33.1543125905,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":74.1352966996
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"8.1155789012",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"29216.0840443903",
                     "miles_per_hour":"18153.738444138"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.0855466094",
                     "lunar":"33.277633667",
                     "kilometers":"12797591",
                     "miles":"7952054.5"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2469737?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"2469737",
            "name":"469737 (2005 NW44)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2469737",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":20.4,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.2210828104,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.4943561926
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":221.0828103591,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":494.3561926196
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.137374447,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.3071786018
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":725.3373275385,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":1621.9035709942
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"12.0629682412",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"43426.685668464",
                     "miles_per_hour":"26983.6536588298"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.0548729224",
                     "lunar":"21.3455677032",
                     "kilometers":"8208872.5",
                     "miles":"5100757"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "links":{  
               "self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3797700?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "neo_reference_id":"3797700",
            "name":"(2018 BC)",
            "nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3797700",
            "absolute_magnitude_h":29.4,
            "estimated_diameter":{  
               "kilometers":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0035039264,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0078350176
               },
               "meters":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":3.5039264111,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":7.8350176433
               },
               "miles":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":0.0021772383,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":0.0048684527
               },
               "feet":{  
                  "estimated_diameter_min":11.4958219265,
                  "estimated_diameter_max":25.705439285
               }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":false,
            "close_approach_data":[  
               {  
                  "close_approach_date":"2018-06-16",
                  "epoch_date_close_approach":1529132400000,
                  "relative_velocity":{  
                     "kilometers_per_second":"1.8772738596",
                     "kilometers_per_hour":"6758.1858945152",
                     "miles_per_hour":"4199.2738965114"
                  },
                  "miss_distance":{  
                     "astronomical":"0.0713602174",
                     "lunar":"27.7591247559",
                     "kilometers":"10675336",
                     "miles":"6633346.5"
                  },
                  "orbiting_body":"Earth"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Yes I believe I will use the createElement method now. Will this allow me to dynamically add tables to my html page at runtime? My objective is to have a table for each asteroid with name, mass, velocity etc. however the number of asteroids and therefore tables will be different each day

Comment: Of course this can be done client side with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
var day = "2018-06-09";
var result = {"links":{"next":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-14&end_date=2018-06-21&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS","prev":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-05-31&end_date=2018-06-07&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS","self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-07&end_date=2018-06-14&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"},"element_count":40,"near_earth_objects":{"2018-06-09":[{"links":{"self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2162474?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"},"neo_reference_id":"2162474","name":"162474 (2000 LB16)","nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2162474","absolute_magnitude_h":18.5,"estimated_diameter":{"kilometers":{"estimated_diameter_min":0.5303407233,"estimated_diameter_max":1.1858779086},"meters":{"estimated_diameter_min":530.3407233187,"estimated_diameter_max":1185.8779085771},"miles":{"estimated_diameter_min":0.3295383456,"estimated_diameter_max":0.7368701419},"feet":{"estimated_diameter_min":1739.963058693,"estimated_diameter_max":3890.675677576}},"is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":true,"close_approach_data":[{"close_approach_date":"2018-06-09","epoch_date_close_approach":1528527600000,"relative_velocity":{"kilometers_per_second":"29.5006815383","kilometers_per_hour":"106202.4535379664","miles_per_hour":"65990.074533077"},"miss_distance":{"astronomical":"0.2778177136","lunar":"108.0710983276","kilometers":"41560940","miles":"25824772"},"orbiting_body":"Earth"}]}]}};

result.near_earth_objects[day].forEach(({name}, i) => document.getElementById('n'+(i+1)).innerHTML = name);
```

```html
<div id="n1"></div>
```

Also, you can improve your code like following

```js
var day = "2018-06-09";
var result = {"links":{"next":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-14&end_date=2018-06-21&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS","prev":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-05-31&end_date=2018-06-07&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS","self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-07&end_date=2018-06-14&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"},"element_count":40,"near_earth_objects":{"2018-06-09":[{"links":{"self":"https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2162474?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"},"neo_reference_id":"2162474","name":"162474 (2000 LB16)","nasa_jpl_url":"http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2162474","absolute_magnitude_h":18.5,"estimated_diameter":{"kilometers":{"estimated_diameter_min":0.5303407233,"estimated_diameter_max":1.1858779086},"meters":{"estimated_diameter_min":530.3407233187,"estimated_diameter_max":1185.8779085771},"miles":{"estimated_diameter_min":0.3295383456,"estimated_diameter_max":0.7368701419},"feet":{"estimated_diameter_min":1739.963058693,"estimated_diameter_max":3890.675677576}},"is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid":true,"close_approach_data":[{"close_approach_date":"2018-06-09","epoch_date_close_approach":1528527600000,"relative_velocity":{"kilometers_per_second":"29.5006815383","kilometers_per_hour":"106202.4535379664","miles_per_hour":"65990.074533077"},"miss_distance":{"astronomical":"0.2778177136","lunar":"108.0710983276","kilometers":"41560940","miles":"25824772"},"orbiting_body":"Earth"}]}]}};

let asteroids = result.near_earth_objects[day];
for (let i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('n'+(i+1)).innerHTML = asteroids[i].name;
}
```

```html
<div id="n1"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone. Yes turns out I just needeed to do:

```
for (let i=0; i<result.near_earth_objects[today].length; i++) {

        let id = 'n'+(i+1);

        let output = document.getElementById(id);
        output.innerHTML = result.near_earth_objects[today][i].name;
    }
```

And thanks strah output.innerhtml was also causing an error...

Comment: Apart from correcting the mistake in your code, an important aspect is to get the appropriate code as well. In the code that you have shared in question is not the right way to do it. There are unnecessary loops which should be avoided.

Comment: Yep I literally didn't need any of the previous loops. I removed those as well as correcting the mistake. Appreciate you all taking the time to help me. First question here, what a great community!

Answer (score -1):

I had to fake the api call, I didn't have a key. One thing I saw was that I needed to compare y with the actual date. This might just be a result of my mocking the returned result. Then the innerHTML, as you saw, had to be case corrected. FWIW, here's a working example.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Asteroids</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="n1"></div> 
    <script>
        var today = "2018-06-09";
        var result = {
            "links": {
                "next": "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-14&end_date=2018-06-21&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
                "prev": "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-05-31&end_date=2018-06-07&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS",
                "self": "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-06-07&end_date=2018-06-14&detailed=false&api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
            },
            "element_count": 40,
            "near_earth_objects": {
                "2018-06-09": [{
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/2162474?api_key=IJtQgGp7nIbexsC9MZm9R3nYPtS2H51ykAQ5PrHS"
                    },
                    "neo_reference_id": "2162474",
                    "name": "162474 (2000 LB16)",
                    "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2162474",
                    "absolute_magnitude_h": 18.5,
                    "estimated_diameter": {
                        "kilometers": {
                            "estimated_diameter_min": 0.5303407233,
                            "estimated_diameter_max": 1.1858779086
                        },
                        "meters": {
                            "estimated_diameter_min": 530.3407233187,
                            "estimated_diameter_max": 1185.8779085771
                        },
                        "miles": {
                            "estimated_diameter_min": 0.3295383456,
                            "estimated_diameter_max": 0.7368701419
                        },
                        "feet": {
                            "estimated_diameter_min": 1739.963058693,
                            "estimated_diameter_max": 3890.675677576
                        }
                    },
                    "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": true,
                    "close_approach_data": [{
                        "close_approach_date": "2018-06-09",
                        "epoch_date_close_approach": 1528527600000,
                        "relative_velocity": {
                            "kilometers_per_second": "29.5006815383",
                            "kilometers_per_hour": "106202.4535379664",
                            "miles_per_hour": "65990.074533077"
                        },
                        "miss_distance": {
                            "astronomical": "0.2778177136",
                            "lunar": "108.0710983276",
                            "kilometers": "41560940",
                            "miles": "25824772"
                        },
                        "orbiting_body": "Earth"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        };
        (function () { 
            // iterate over all keys
            for (let x in result) { 
                // if key is 'near_earth_objects'
                if (x == 'near_earth_objects') { 
                    // iterate over dates in 'near_earth_objects'
                    for (y in result.near_earth_objects) { 
                        // if todays date
                        if (y == today) { //Check y with today's value

                            // loop over array of objects for todays date
                            for (let i = 0; i < result.near_earth_objects[today].length; i++) {


                                let id = 'n' + (i + 1);

                                let output = document.getElementById(id);
                                output.innerHTML = result.near_earth_objects[today][i].name;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })();
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```